# Make dataframe into wide format and group columns by pairing

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that can be simplified to this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  PID = c(1091, 1358, 1087, 2358, 2087, 2091),
  value = c('1','2', '1,4,6', '2', '2', '1')
)
```

I want to do a few things with this dataframe:

1. make this dataframe into a wide format where `PID`s are grouped together by the last 1-3 digits, with `value` spread out in wide format accordingly.
2. Then, based on the pairing of `value` for each `PID` group, create a new column `category` based on the following pairing:

- if `value_A` and `value_B` are 1 and 2 (who's who does not matter, as long as the pairing is 1 and 2 for both `PID`s), `category` should be "mw"
- if `value_A` and `value_B` are the same number (e.g. 1+1 or 2+2), `category` should be "mm"
- all other value pairings should give "other" in `category`

This is the solution dataframe:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  PID_A = c(1091, 1358, 1087),
  PID_B = c(2091, 2358, 2087),
  value_A = c('1','2', '1,4,6'),
  value_B = c('1', '2', '2'),
  category = c("mw", "mm", "other")
)
```

Does anyone have any insight on how I may achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried something? You could at first split the digits . Idea 1: by considering them as character. Idea 2: using modular math ex 
example2 = example %>% 
  mutate(PID_firstdigit =PID%/%1000 ,
         PID_3digits = PID%%1000
         )

Comment: Your output is inconsistent: in `example`, 2091 is `1` but in the output it is `2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

example %>%
  separate_wider_position(PID, c(a=1, b = 3), cols_remove = FALSE)%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = a, values_from = c(PID, value), 
              names_glue = "{.value}_{c(`1` = 'A', `2` = 'B')[a]}") %>%
  mutate(category = case_when(
           value_A == value_B ~ 'mm',
           value_A == 1 & value_B== 2 ~ 'mw',
           value_A == 2 & value_B== 1 ~ 'mw', 
           .default = 'other'), b = NULL)

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  PID_A PID_B value_A value_B category
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   
1  1091  2091 1       2       mw      
2  1358  2358 2       2       mm      
3  1087  2087 1,4,6   2       other
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, no pivot required:

```r
library(dplyr)
mutate(example, three = PID %% 1000) %>%
  full_join(., ., by = "three", suffix = c("_A", "_B")) %>%
  filter(PID_A < PID_B) |>
  mutate(
    condition = case_when(
      value_A != value_B & min(value_A, value_B) == 1 & max(value_A, value_B) == 2 ~ "mw",
      value_A == value_B & value_A == 2 ~ "mm",
      .default = "other")
  )
#   PID_A value_A three PID_B value_B condition
# 1  1091       1    91  2091       1     other
# 2  1358       2   358  2358       2        mm
# 3  1087   1,4,6    87  2087       2        mw
```

Answer (score 1):

a `data .table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# split to list based on laste 3 digits from PID
L <- split(setDT(example), f = substr(example$PID, 2,4), keep.by = FALSE)
# loop over list, create data.table from values, bing together
final <- lapply(L, function(x) data.table(names = names(unlist(x)), unlist(x))) |> rbindlist(idcol = "id")
# cast to wide and annd category
dcast(final, id ~ names, value.var = "V2")[, category := fifelse(value1 == value2, "mm", "other")][]

#        id   PID1   PID2 value1 value2 category
#    <char> <char> <char> <char> <char>   <char>
# 1:    087   1087   2087  1,4,6      2    other
# 2:    091   1091   2091      1      1       mm
# 3:    358   1358   2358      2      2       mm
```